# Detect how many concurrent requests before current request

Tags: asp.net, iis, concurrency

I am using ASP.NET 4.0 with IIS 7.5 for my web application.There are a lots of  concurrent requests.

When a client send request .How to detect how many  concurrent requests before current request .Then ,I would like to hint the user.Please queue...

To check the iis queue pool? I have no ideas .Thanks！

Answer (score 0):

You could get the data by [`PerformanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb29hack%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class, as [you could get it from System Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/fxk122b4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).